# Finding base file name in an un-existing one windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In windows, if I want to find the base name of a file in cmd I can do:

```
for /F %i in (%newest_file%) do set FILENAME=%~ni%~xi
```

However, if `%newest_file%` doesn't really exist on windows machine e.g.

```
export/xiv0/webroot/Builds/client.is_11_3_1.win.RC1.4.140929.zip
```

I get file not found.

What do I do in this case? how can I find in windows batch the base name of a string representing a potential file?

Comment: Where is `%newest_file%` defined and set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `/f` switch in your `for` statement.

```
for %I in ("non existent file.txt") do @echo %~nI
```

will return `non existent file`.

By the way, you can also combine those tilde modifiers.  `%~nxI` will return name + ext with no path.  You don't have to do `%~nI%~xI`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `FOR` command! Your `FOR /F` command will attempt to open the file and iterate each line. So it is not giving the base name of `%newest_file%`, even if it exists. Instead it is treating each line within the file as a file name, and giving the base name of that.

Also, you can combine `%~ni%~xi` into `%~nxi`.

What you want is a simple `FOR` command - this will work whether or not the file exists:

```
for %F in ("%newest_file%") do set "FILENAME=%~nxF"
```

Comment: @Dejel I'll bump his karma on your behalf.  :)